# FTP Files from a Server that has Input parameter on Login

Tags: java, file, ftp, ftp-client

I am Using the following method to FTP files from a remote server to a local machine. This works fine if the Server on Login does not have an input parameter. But I have this server which is such that after I login I have to type 1 and enter for it to go to the Home page. So when I run this Code on the server, by default it goes to the home page instead of the working directory. How Can I achieve this?
My Method;:

```
public void FtpFiles() {
        try {

            //new ftp client
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
            //try to connect
            ftp.connect("FtpServerName");
            //login to server
            if (!ftp.login("serverusername", "serverpassword")) {
                ftp.logout();
            }
            int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
            //FTPReply stores a set of constants for FTP reply codes. 
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftp.disconnect();
            }
            //enter passive mode
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            //get system name
            System.out.println("Remote system is " + ftp.getSystemType());
            //change current directory
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/ftadm/home/users/Statements/testStatements");
            System.out.println("Current Statement directory is " + ftp.printWorkingDirectory());

            //get list of filenames
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();
            if (ftpFiles != null && ftpFiles.length > 0) {
                //loop thru files
                for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
                    if (!file.isFile()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Moving File File " + file.getName());
                    //get output stream
                    OutputStream output;
                    output = new FileOutputStream(pr.getHomeDirName() + file.getName());
                    //get the file from the remote system
                    ftp.retrieveFile(file.getName(), output);
                    //close output stream
                    output.close();
                    //delete the file
                    if (pr.deleteRemoteFiles() == true) {            
                        ftp.deleteFile(file.getName());
                    }
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Remote Directory is Empty");
            }
            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Am using Apache FTP Client API

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  Are you using some command-line or GUI-based FTP client when you "type 1 and enter"?  What client?

Comment: I am using Putty Client